# Particular question about past

Tags: grammar, difference, past-tense

> 1. He knew that I was trying to tell him the fact **that him being
>      wrong.**
> 2. He knew that I was trying to tell him the fact **which is him being
>      wrong.**
> 3. He knew that I was trying to tell him the
>      **fact that he is wrong.**
> 4. He knew that I was trying to tell him the **fact that he was
>      wrong.**

I am confused about whether these are right or not. Are you supposed to turn every Present Simple verbs to past simple if you are talking about the past?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main thing you are trying to understand better is getting obscured by the way you're using "the fact that."  Let me rephrase your question, to focus on what I think you are asking:

> 1. He knew that I was trying to tell him he is wrong.

> 2. He knew that I was trying to tell him he was wrong.

> Are these both possible?

The answer is yes, they are both possible, although in many cases, people would typically choose (2).

Now I will say something about sentences that include "the fact that."  Here are some acceptable sentences:

> a. I was trying to tell him the fact that whales are dying in record numbers.

> b. The fact is that whales are dying in record numbers.

> c. He was not aware of the fact that whales are dying in record numbers.

> d. The fact is, whales are dying in record numbers.

> e. I was trying to tell him that "whales are dying in record numbers" is an incorrect statement.

Those are all acceptable sentences.  It is extremely common for even native speakers of English to get themselves tied up in knots with sentences that include "the fact that."  I recommend that English learners avoid using it!  But if you do feel a strong need to use "the fact that," I suggest you try to fit your sentence into one of the patterns (a) through (d).

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly to do with the subcategorisation frames of *fact* - the particular kinds of complements it can take.

*Fact* can take either:

> A finite clause introduced by *that*: "the fact that he was wrong"

or

> A (non-finite) gerund clause introduced by *of*: "the fact of his/him* being wrong"

Your 1. is ungrammatical.

Your 2. is probably grammatical, but it is not idiomatic. Using "the fact which is/was" asserts that it is actually a fact, and then says more about it, whereas "the fact of/that" uses "fact" as a placeholder, and doesn't really assert anything about it.

Your 3. and 4. are both grammatical. 4. is much more likely, but 3. is possible, if what you are saying is that he was not just wrong at that moment, but continues to be wrong. (This is the only issue where being in the past is relevant to your question).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you tell me why the 1 is ungrammatical?

Comment: Also "He knew that I was trying to tell him the fact that **he was being wrong.** Is it correct?

Comment: @lollel123: because 1 doesn't match either of the frames. _that_ introduces a **finite** clause. "Him being wrong" is a non-finite (gerund) clause.